# How to execute Erlang programs in parallel?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

This is part of function of my program:

```
case is_html(Headers) of
{true,_} ->
      UTFBody=convert_to_utf8(Headers,RawBody),
      ParsedBody=mochiweb_html:parse(UTFBody),
      Desc=get_head(search_tag(ParsedBody,?DESC)),
      Title=get_head(search_tag(ParsedBody,?TITLE)),
      SiteName=get_head(search_tag(ParsedBody,?SITENAME)),
      CONURL=get_head(search_tag(ParsedBody,?URL)),
      Author=get_head(search_tag(ParsedBody,?AUTHOR)),
      Image=get_head(search_tag(ParsedBody,?IMAGE)),
      {Desc,Title,SiteName,CONURL,Author,Image};
{false,Ext} ->
   .........
```

All the statements are independent, how the program can be modified that the lines of program execute in parallel and takes less execution time.

Any help is appreciable.

edit:

`get_head/1` returns `head` of `list`.

`search_tag/2` have one `lists:foldl` implementation.

Comment: How long does it take to execute each of those `get_head` right now? Executing them in parallel will only be faster if the overhead of spawning a process and copying the necessary data structures into the new process takes less time than each `get_head` does right now.

Comment: Use profiling first, then try to parallelize code like this. I bet it is not a good idea. Amdahl's law will kill it. Optimize your `get_head/1` `search_tag/2` code first. Probably transform `ParsedBody` to a better structure.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil `get_head/1` is small code which returns head of `list`.Which better structure you are referring to?

Comment: @MandeepSingh what about `search_tag/2`? how slow/fast is that?

Comment: @Dogbert I've edited the question. Can you suggest any way it can be done?

Comment: @MandeepSingh: [Erlang Profiling](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html). In your case, you should use `eprof` or better `fprof` in testing environment. But definitely start with [`timer:tc/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-3).